# syntaxerror: expected expression, got '}' in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a select option and when I select an option it must show my colors

Look at my codes

```
<?php foreach ($colors as $color) { ?>
    <option onclick=addColor("<?php echo $color->title ?>", this) value="<?= $color->id ?>"><?= $color->title ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

script

```
function addColor(color_name, tag) {
    var optionTag = $(tag);
    var selectColor = '<span class="select-color mr-1"><img src="public/images/dialog_close.png">+color_name+</span>';
    var divRow = optionTag.parents('.row');
    divRow.append(selectColor);
}
```

but  i get this error.

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: First you need an ' at: your onclick tag: ->   <option onclick='addColor("<?php echo $color->title ?>", this)' value="[...]></option

Answer (score 0):

Try

**PHP**
You are not defining the end and beginning of your onclick attribute, enclose it with " " as you also need a string parameter to your method enclose it with ' ' as to not terminate the attribute string prematurely.

```
<option onclick="addColor('<?php echo $color->title ?>', this)" value="<?= $color->id ?>"><?= $color->title ?></option>
```

**Javascript**
Terminate your string around the variable to indicate that the variable is to be appended to the string. If you just write + var + inside a string that will be a normal part of the string.

```
var selectColor = '<span class="select-color mr-1"><img src="public/images/dialog_close.png">'+color_name+'</span>';
```

You are also mixing output methods in your PHP, I would recommend sticking to one kind of make it easier to read your code.